# Copy a freeform object in python-pptx

Tags: python, powerpoint, python-pptx

I have a freeform object in a template slide that I'd like to duplicate and make multiple objects out of.

I couldn't find in the documentation a way to create a shape from a pre-existing shape. Am I looking in the wrong place or does that functionality not exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `python-pptx` API has no support for this operation, but you may be able to use some internals to accomplish this result

```
from copy import deepcopy

# ---get the existing freeform shape however you do---
freeform = slide.shapes[n]
# ---get the underlying XML element for that shape---
sp = freeform._sp
for idx in range(3):
    # ---duplicate original freeform---
    new_sp = deepcopy(sp)
    # ---create a unique id for it---
    new_sp.nvSpPr.cNvPr.id = 1000 + idx
    # ---insert it after original---
    sp.addnext(new_sp)
```

These will all be stacked directly on top of the original, so you might want to add some to move them to a new position. Also, you might run into trouble if the existing freeform participates in a hyperlink, either by itself being a link or text it contains having a hyperlink.

Comment: Thanks Steve! a small note, the way to set the id seems to be `new_sp.nvSpPr.cNvPr.id = new_id`. Also, `_sp` is the auto shape element, right? Is there a way to move it besides accessing `new_sp.spPr.xfrm.off.x = new_x`

Comment: You'll find the new shapes in the shapes collection after this code runs, so something like `new_shape = slide.shapes[n+1]` or whatever. The new shape will be immediately subsequent to the original (assuming you use `.addnext()`).